# Sum of the objects in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I am trying to code with a Django ecommerce plugin called [django-cart](https://github.com/bmentges/django-cart). I want to find the sum of the prices of all items in the cart. The cart model has the following code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Cart(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('creation date'))
    checked_out = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('checked out'))
    def _valor_carrinho(self):
        return self.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('total_price'))
    valor_carrinho = property(_valor_carrinho)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('cart')
        verbose_name_plural = _('carts')
        ordering = ('-creation_date',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.creation_date)    

class ItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'product' in kwargs:
            kwargs['content_type'] = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(kwargs['product']))
            kwargs['object_id'] = kwargs['product'].pk
            del(kwargs['product'])
        return super(ItemManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

class Item(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, verbose_name=_('cart'))
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_('quantity'))
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('unit price'))
    # product as generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    link_item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo_item = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cor_item = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    modelo_item = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    tamanho_item = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    objects = ItemManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('item')
        verbose_name_plural = _('items')
        ordering = ('cart',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d units of %s' % (self.quantity, self.product.__class__.__name__)

    def total_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.unit_price
    total_price = property(total_price)

    # product
    def get_product(self):
        return self.content_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=self.object_id)

    def set_product(self, product):
        self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(product))
        self.object_id = product.pk

    product = property(get_product, set_product)
```

And I am trying to use `valor_carrinho` (sorry for the mixup between Portuguese and English in the code) as the sum of the `total_price` field of all the items in the cart. But when I use it in a template, it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
def _valor_carrinho(self):
    return self.item_set.all().aggregate(Sum('total_price'))
```

to get all items for a specific `Cart` instance,  I am NOT sure `total_price` works here, but to access the items of the cart it is `item_set`, hopefully it is enough to get you started!

The concept that that is using is reverse foreign key lookup, which is explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Comment: Seems like i'm having a problem with the template. Still trying to fix it, but your answer seems to work :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this does work as I think aggregate goes to the database layer and total_price has been defined as a property.  I am going to denormalise and make the equivalent of total_price a field so that I can use the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it works for me so it might work for you:

#### view.py

```
def get_cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.summary()
    return render_to_response('cart.html', dict(cart=Cart(request)),{'cart':cart})
```

#### cart.html

```
<h3> Total : {{ cart.summary }}</h3>
```